# When we apply LH rule to evaluate a limit ,the new function we obtain is exact or approaching?

Tags: calculus, limits

If we have to evaluate a $0/0$ indeterminate form then we apply LH rule
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$ or is it $$\lim_{x\to0}\large{\to}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
for eg - lim x->0 sinx/x is lim x->0 cosx or lim x->0 (->cosx)
-> symbol stands for approaching value
LH rule=L'hospital's rule

Comment: I don't see that the second expression has any meaning.

Comment: The first one. The question you're asking about in the second one is the whole point of having the limits in L'Hopital's rule. Generally, $f(x)/g(x) \neq f'(x)/g'(x)$, but under the appropriate conditions, in the limit as $f(x)\to 0$ and $g(x) \to 0$, the *limits* of the ratios *are* equal.

Comment: For future readers, the current "second expression" is different from what it was [originally](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4172071/1).

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $\lim_{x\to 0} \to$? This is the first time I am looking at such notation and it is not available in typical textbooks. Perhaps you should elaborate your thought process behind this and then we can clarify any issues.

Answer (score -1):

They are basically the same thing, but the notation of the first one makes a lot more sense:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\qquad\text{where   }f(\epsilon)=g(\epsilon)=0,\epsilon\to0$$
Whilst they are equal, that does not mean they converge in the same manner if that is what you mean, they just converge to the same value.

Comment: I wanted to know this because i have another question .I will ask it soon ,please see to it .                       Thanks]